# How can I return the best matched row first in sort order from a set returned by querying a single search term against multiple columns in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, sql-order-by

**Background**

I have a Postgres 11 table like so:

```
       CREATE TABLE
        some_schema.foo_table (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
            bar_text TEXT,
            foo_text TEXT,
            foobar_text TEXT
        );
```

It has some data like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_schema.foo_table (bar_text, foo_text, foobar_text)
        VALUES ('eddie', '123456', 'something0987');
        INSERT INTO some_schema.foo_table (bar_text, foo_text, foobar_text)
        VALUES ('Snake', '12345-54321', 'that_@#$%_snake');
         INSERT INTO some_schema.foo_table (bar_text, foo_text, foobar_text)
        VALUES ('Sally', '12345', '24-7avocado');

 id | bar_text |  foo_text   |   foobar_text   
----+----------+-------------+-----------------
  1 | eddie    | 123456       | something0987
  2 | Snake    | 12345-54321 | that_@#$%_snake
  3 | Sally    | 12345        | 24-7avocado
```

**The problem**

I need to query each one of these columns and compare the values to a given term (passed in as an argument from app logic), and make sure the best-matched row (considering comparison with all the columns, not just one) is returned ***first*** in the sort order.
There is no way to know in advance which of the columns is likely to be a better match for the given term.

If I compare the given term to each value using the similarity() function, I can see at a glance which row has the best match in ***any of the three columns*** and can see that's the one I would want ranked first in the sort order.

```
   SELECT 
    f.id,
    f.foo_text, 
    f.bar_text,
    f.foobar_text,
    similarity('12345', foo_text) AS foo_similarity,
    similarity('12345', bar_text) AS bar_similarity,
    similarity('12345', foobar_text) AS foobar_similarity
    FROM some_schema.foo_table f
    WHERE 
    (
        f.foo_text ILIKE '%12345%' 
        OR
        f.bar_text ILIKE '%12345%'
        OR 
        f.foobar_text ILIKE '%12345%'
        )
        ;
 id |  foo_text   | bar_text |   foobar_text   | foo_similarity | bar_similarity | foobar_similarity 
----+-------------+----------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------
  2 | 12345-54321 | Snake    | that_@#$%_snake |            0.5 |              0 |                 0
  3 | 12345       | Sally    | 24-7avocado     |              1 |              0 |                 0
  1 | 123456      | eddie    | something0987   |          0.625 |              0 |                 0
(3 rows)
```

Clearly in this case, id #3 (Sally) is the best match (exact, as it happens); this is the row I'd like to return first.

**However, since I don't know ahead of time that foo_text is going to be the column with the best match, I don't know how to define the ORDER BY clause.**

I figured this would be a common enough problem, but I haven't found any hints in a fair bit of SO and DDG .

How can I always rank the best-matched row first in the returned set, without knowing which column will provide the best match to the search term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `greatest()`:

```
greatest(similarity('12345', foo_text), similarity('12345', bar_text), similarity('12345', foobar_text)) desc
```

Comment: A full statement would be nice here. I would also be helped in knowing if regex works in the second parameter of `similarity` so something like this would say the second similarity is greatest (I'm just getting errors): `select greatest(similarity('FOOBAZ', '^FOO'), similarity('FOOBAZ', '^FOOB'), similarity('FOOBAZ', '^OOBAZ'))`